# Compass SASS - downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer

Tags: css, sass, font-face, compass-sass

I know there is numerous questions asked here about this issue. I have no intention of duplicating the questions. I have tried all kinds of proposed solutions, but non of them have solved it for me.

I'm using [compass SASS syntax](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/font-face/). And all the files lives in `/static` directory.

I've tried single quotes instead of doubled quotes, and removing .eot from `_fonts.sass` file. I've also read somewhere that it solved the issue removing the trailing `?1400417483`, but I don't know to do that, since it is auto-generated by compass.

console error:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "circular-book" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff?1400417483
app.css:70:11
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "circular-book" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1) source: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff2?1465294178
```

config.rb

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
fonts_dir = "fonts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

_fonts.sass

```
@import compass/css3

+font-face("circular-book", font-files("lineto-circular-book.woff", "lineto-circular-book.woff2"))

$font: "circular-book", sans-serif
```

app.sass

```
html
  font-family: $font
```

app.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "circular-book";
  src: url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff?1400417483') format('woff'), url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff2?1465294178') format('woff2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION.

It resolved the issue to adding `$eot, $weight, $style` by changing `_fonts.sass` from

```
+font-face("circular-book", font-files("lineto-circular-book.woff", "lineto-circular-book.woff2"))
```

to

```
+font-face("circular-book", font-files("lineto-circular-book.woff", "lineto-circular-book.woff2"), "lineto-circular-book.eot", normal, normal)
```

and the resulting app.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "circular-book";
  src: url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.eot?1400417483');
  src: url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.eot?&1400417483#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff?1400417483') format('woff'), url('../fonts/lineto-circular-book.woff2?1465294178') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Firefox hides a not found error under this 'rejected by sanitizer'. Double check if you are routing the font file properly and that it is deployed

[I found this helpful information here](https://www.seanmcp.com/articles/fix-downloadable-font-rejected-by-sanitizer-error-in-firefox/)